# Infinite loop in AbstractOioByteChannel

Tags: netty

I'm not sure that infinite loop in the AbstractOioByteChannel.doWrite(ChannelOutboundBuffer in) is correct, netty version 4.0.9
Thanks,
-Igor

Comment: Why you think it's not ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add a loop break(bold below) if no message got

```
    *for (;;) {
        Object msg = in.current();
        **if (msg == null) {
            break;
        }**
        if (msg instanceof ByteBuf) {
            ....
        } else if (msg instanceof FileRegion) {
            ...
        } else {
            in.remove(new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "unsupported message type: " + StringUtil.simpleClassName(msg)));
        }
    }*
```